# Android PopupWindow and SeekBar listener not responding

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-popupwindow

Does anyone know why my seekbar listener is not picking up any data from the seekbar?? i have it all setup and working but it isnt updating the textviews, i think it has something to do with the popup window using a different activity layout to the activity it sits inside

```
public class Environment extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener
{

private ImageButton lockButton;


SeekBar bar;
TextView textProgress, textAction;
private PopupWindow pwindo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setup_environment);

    lockButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.lock);
    lockButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            initiatePopupWindow();

        }
    });

}


private void initiatePopupWindow() {
    try {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Environment.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.annotation,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
        pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, 1000, 1200, true);
        pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1); // make seekbar object
        bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        textProgress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewProgress);

        textAction = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewAction);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                              boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    textProgress.setText("The value is: "+progress);

    textAction.setText("changing");
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    textAction.setText("starting to track touch");

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(seekBar.getProgress());
    textAction.setText("ended tracking touch");
}
```

}
Whenever i use the slider it should update with the int value 0-100 depending on where the slider is, it works if i create an activity and use it straight away, but when i put it in a popupwindow it doesnt do anything??

annotation.xml

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/popup_element"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#65bea9"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="10sp">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:hint="@string/hint_annotation"
    android:scrollIndicators="right"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:textSize="8pt"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewProgress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="progress displayed here"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="6pt"></TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewAction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewProgress"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="action displayed here"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="6pt"></TextView>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:layout_gravity="center"></SeekBar>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_close_popup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/btn_submit"/>
```

setup environment xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/root"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context=".Activities.Environment">


    <ImageButton
        android:src="@mipmap/unlocked_syn"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/lock"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="11" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the full code of this activity

Comment: I have updated with full activity

Comment: Are you trying to put your seekbar in the popup window? Have you declared your seekbar in the activity xml or annotation xml ?

Comment: Thats right yes, the seekbar is in a popupwindow.  I have declared it inside annotation.xml

Comment: Can  you please post your activity and annotation xml, cause I feel there are some problems with your code !!

Comment: i have posted annotation.xml which is the layout for the popupwindow, i think it has something to with this `setContentView(R.layout.setup_environment);`

Comment: Please post the activity xml as well i.e setup_environment xml, I need to confirm before suggestion a solution !!

Comment: Updated the include all xml files

Comment: Please have a look at my answer !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you should be initializing your Seekbar etc by the views from the layout. Simply doing findViewById searches for the views in the activity

```
private void initiatePopupWindow() {
    try {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Environment.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.annotation,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
        pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, 1000, 1200, true);
        pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        bar = (SeekBar)layout.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1); // make seekbar object
        bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        textProgress = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textViewProgress);

        textAction = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textViewAction);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! works exactly as it should now :)  So the problem was i was looking for resources from a different context?  And by doing layout.findView....  it looks inside this for resources?

Comment: Yes, when your do findViewById it basically searches for the views in the activity xml. The views however are not present there. When you do layout.findView .. it will look in the layout view, which in your case is the inflated annotation view, inside which the views are present. Basically layout refers to this layout --> View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.annotation,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));

Comment: Thanks thats makes a lot more sense now.  Thanks again you have helped a lot :)

Comment: You have to build your statue on this simple help solving a lot of problems